# make: trigger without rebuilding dependency

Tags: makefile

Basically I have the usual Makefile construct:

```
target: dependency1 dependency2 dependency3
      runtargetscript.sh
```

However in this case, the target only needs one of the dependencies and some dependencies may not be buildable. (so I cannot just build all dependencies)

Is it possible to tell make to trigger "target" when one of the dependencies changed/was created (i.e. normal behaviour) but NOT to try to rebuild any missing dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU make you can use shell escapes to build the dependencies dynamically, adding them only if they already exist:

```
if_exist = $(shell if [ -e $(1) ]; then echo $(1); fi)

target: $(call if_exist,dependency1) $(call if_exist,dependency2) $(call if_exist,dependency3)
        runtargetscript.sh
```

This will run the script if target does not exist, or if it is older than any of the dependencies that do exist *at the time the makefile was read*, but will not attempt to build them if they do not exist at that time.

Note the important caveat there -- if the file(s) do not exist, but some other unrelated rule runs an action that creates them, it won't rebuild target, unless you rerun `make target` again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your rule body does not do anything special depending on which dependencies are newer than the target you can use the `-W` flag to make to instruct it to consider certain targets as always new (and thus not in need of building).

So for the given example assuming you can (and want) to build `dependency2` but not `dependency1` or `dependency3` you would run:

```
make -W dependency1 -W dependency3 target
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comments this does not work correctly when `dependency2` is not newer than `target` as `target` will still be built.

In that case I believe the only solution (given the comments below) is to use something like:

```
DEPENDENCY_BIN := $(or $(wildcard /path/to/mysql),$(wildcard /path/to/sqlite3),/path/that/does/not/exist)

target: $(DEPENDENCY_BIN) dependency2
```

Comment: No, that doesn't word because (1) a missing dependency causes a failure and (2) it would in all cases trigger the target, even if no dependency was changed

Comment: @Robby75 1) If a missing dependency means the target fails to build then I don't see how you can get what you want at all. 2) No, that will only trigger if `dependency2` is newer than `target` given my command.

Comment: 1) An installation needs either the MySQL-binary *OR* the Sqlite3-binary, but not both - and the project should compile fine without either as long as at least one is available

Comment: 2) from the manpage: -W file, --what-if=file, --new-file=file, --assume-new=file
Pretend that the target file has just been modified. When used with the -n flag, this shows you what would happen if you were to modify that file. Without -n, it is almost the same as running a touch command on the given file before running make, except that the modification time is changed only in the imagination of make. --- END --- This means that target would always be triggered, because -W dependency1 will cause dependency1 to be (assumed) newer than target.

Comment: Hm... True. I was not properly thinking that through for point two. My apologies.